# Change the default #lang line in DrRacket

Tags: racket

When DrRacket starts up, and the language is set to `Determine Language From Source` (aka not the student languages), DrRacket starts every new file with a default line:

```
#lang racket
```

Normally this is good because its a nice default for writing quick scripts, throw away examples, etc. And if you want a more specific language, say `racket/base`, its easy enough to go change it.

However, the `racket` language lacks a few features that I find really nice for quick scratch work. The [`agile`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/agile/index.html) language however does have many of the libraries that I want included by default. However, replacing the `racket` with `agile` is just as annoying as writing out `(require syntax/parse/define)`.

Is there a way I can tell DrRacket to change my default `#lang`? That way new files will start with:

```
#lang agile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it actually is possible to change the default language DrRacket uses for new files.

To change this setting go to: Languages -> Choose Language -> Show Details

and at the bottom right corner you will see `Automatic #lang line`. Change that to whatever you want and that will be the first line of new Racket files. Click Ok and your preference is set.